# How to calculate the covariance matrix of a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, covariance-matrix

I have a big pyspark data frame with the columns as some products and the rows as its prices over time. I need to calculate the covariance matrix of all the products, but the data is too big to convert to a pandas data frame, so I need to do it with pyspark. I've searched it everywhere but I couldn't figure out a solution to this problem. Does anyone have an idea to how it could be done?

I already have the correlation matrix, so any method using the diagonal matrix of standard deviations is also very welcome.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuoRf.jpg) is an example of two columns of my dataframe.

Comment: Actually, the copiable/pastable version of your data was better than the screenshot you refer to.

Comment: Have you tried using he built in function: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#covar_pop?

Comment: Yeah it calculates the covariance between two columns of the data frame, but I'm not sure on how to create the covariance matrix from it

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of linear algebra functions in SparkML. You are probably looking for one of the `RowMatrix` methods, specifically  `computeCovariance()` ([Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeCovariance)).

Assuming you are looking for the equivalent of:

```
dummy = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,1]])
dummy.cov()
```

Then you can, starting from a `dataframe`, compute the covariance matrix using pyspark with something like the following:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 1]])
vector_col = "cov_features"
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=df.columns, outputCol=vector_col, handleInvalid="skip")
df_vector = assembler.transform(df).select(vector_col)
mat_df = RowMatrix(df_vector)
mat_df = RowMatrix(df_vector.rdd.map(list))
result_df = mat_df.computeCovariance()
```

The vectorization of the `dataframe` is required because the `pyspark.mllib.linalg`is working with vector representations.